# Count number of pixels

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, pixel

I have two layers: polygon and raster. Could you tell me how to count the number of pixels which intersect with polygon layer?  Raster is too large to creating fishnet or convert to vector (time consuming). Also zonal statistic doesn't work because it gives me the average pixel value and not their number. I would ask for help, any program.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Zonal statistic algorithm has the Count operator too.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please decide which GIS product you want to ask about.  You have a tag for QGIS but then your question body says " I would ask for help, any program.".  By asking about more than one you are effectively asking multiple questions which goes against the [Tour]. You should then describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Zonal Statistic you are getting the mean because you are selecting only to collect the mean. you can get more information such as count, sum, mean, median, standard deviation. Anyways, What you want is to make sure Count is selected in the `statistics to calculate` tab. If you don't have the option, you migh have an old version of qgis. I suggest downloading the [latest qgis long term release](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html).
You can do it using pyqgis with this code aswell:

`processing.run("qgis:zonalstatistics", {'INPUT_RASTER':'Your_Input_Raster','RASTER_BAND':1,'INPUT_VECTOR':'Your_Input_Polygon','COLUMN_PREFIX':'Raster_','STATS':[0]})`

Comment: Thanks for help, I used QGIS RasterStats plugin and in stats file was field - pixel count.